# What causes the failure to click buttons that are not in forms when using capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have searched this for some good time in SO, and on Google. I am a newbie(only 7 months in development), but I'd like an explanation as to why capybara's `click_button` does not respond to buttons that are not in forms

take and example of this

```
<div id="btn-div">
  <%= button_tag('Attach new file', id: "attach-file-btn", class: "btn btn-info") %>
</div>
```

in this case when you are writing tests you get an error of the type

```
undefined method `node_name' for nil:NilClass
```

however when you put this in a `form` like this it works

```
<form id="btn-form">
  <%= button_tag('Attach new file', id: "attach-file-btn", class: "btn btn-info") %>
</form>
```

if you may, please provide an explanation as to why this happens.

and take the following into consideration

1. the button is not submitting anything, it is only causing JavaScript to show a form
2. when I try to find the button by using `xpath` or `find` it is available, however `click_button` does not work for it

**update**

code for click button is similar to this:

```
describe "Getting to the deployable tools page" do

  before do       
    @tool = FactoryGirl.create(:tool)
    @tool.set_status(1)
  end
  
  before { visit assigned_tools_path }
  before { click_button('attach-file-btn') }          

  it { should have_content('select tools to add') }
  it { should have_css('#non-successful-tool-adding') }
end
```

Comment: What does your exact code for `click_button` look like? You say you're using it, but you don't show us how you're using it.

Comment: @ChrisPeters the update has been made

Comment: The main issue here is that as soon as I place the button in a form in the view it works

Comment: Have you considered marking it up as a link styled like a button instead?

Comment: @ChrisPeters that has always worked, my major aim was to find out if capybara does not support clicking on button that are not in form, and if so, then someone could help understand why

Answer (score 2):

Try using a capybara finder, and then invoke click on it, like so:

```
page.find('#attach-file-btn').click
```

Comment: I tried without success. my main issue here is that when the button is placed in a form, `click_button` does work, but if it is not it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to click the file show at broswer with text `Attach new file`, use:

```
click_button 'Attach new file'
```

Comment: Can you see this button from broswer and can click it?

Comment: yes, everything works fine. but as I have said, the problem here is that when testing the functionality, `click_button` does not work when the button in the view is not in a like `<form> <button> attach new file </button><form>`

Comment: Is that form button created by Javascript? Try `gem "capybara-webkit"`, capybara not work well with js

Comment: the button is pure html as you can see from the code. I do not know if it is a bug in capybara, but according to what I've seen some issues I have seen in SO, and in some GitHub issues for the capybara repo, this is among them.